# Masters in mathematics with bachelors in different subject

Tags: soft-question

I have a bachelor's degree in electronics engineering, and I'm fairly interested in discrete mathematics, is it possible to study masters in mathematics? If so would it be worth pursing it?

Comment: Why close, I think it is an interesting answer, maybe it is not very objectively written, but I find it useful.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that.  When you ask if its "worth" it, what do you mean?  Financially?  Emotionally?

Comment: I'd say it's possible. Later in life, when you're looking for a job, you will probably find that your bachelors degree in EE is more valuable than your masters in mathematics.

Answer (score 3):

It's certainly possible. Whether it's "worth pursuing" may depend on your goals in life.